# NBGit to remote host with ssh

Tags: java, git, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I´m trying to get that working:

clone a git project from an ssh server with NBGit. I get NBGit installed, works well local, but when given the connection parameters I´m not sure what is the right URL.

Or maybe it is not supported at the moment?

NBGit 0.4 for NB 6.9.1 on Win7

Answer (score 1):

The URL should be:

```
git@myserver:/myreppo
```

[image]

But as reported in [issue 91](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/issues/detail?id=91), that might not work very well.
I would explore the workaround presented in [issue 56](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/issues/detail?id=56):

In your ~/.ssh directory, create a "config" file

open ~/.ssh/config in a text editor and put in the following:

```
Host AHostName -- this will be the name you will be calling in nbgit
User gituser
Hostname SSH IP address --eg 192.68.24.1 --my git server
Port 1234 -- use this if you need custom ports
IdentityFile "path to your private ssh key"
```

From there, the url can be:

```
AHostName:myrepo
```

Comment: @PeterMmm: this works on Windows7 too: define a `HOME` variable and make it reference any directory you want. Then launch Netbeans, making sure `HOME` has been defined first. Your config file will be in `%HOME%/.ssh/config` (or try also `%HOME%/_ssh/config`)