# GitHub, Current Netbeans 6.9 Project, and Git Plugin

Tags: java, git, netbeans, github, repository

Hehehe..
I'm confused.

I already have an account of GitHub. I already have a repo over there.
And then, I already install the Git Client (Git Bash, and Git GUI).
I tried some couple tutorials on that GITHub regarding how to set Its public key, and... touch new file, and... commit it. But all of that are on CommandLine and nor via Netbeans.

And also FYI, i already have my current project on Netbeans. Once I installed the NBGit plugin, i'm wondering....

How to push my current projects (netbeans) to the GitHub repo with the Netbeans?
How to set the current projects (netbeans) to be a default for commiting to gitHub with the Netbeans?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357232/nbgit-to-remote-host-with-ssh might be a good starting point?

Comment: @VonC ok then... I'm still digging many articles thru google as well.
Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can update to Netbeans 7.1 which has git support integrated. You can then just initialise your git repository and then set it up with your git hub account with this tutorial. http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html

Comment: i'm afraid netbeans with Beta stage is not my favourite situation right now...
Anyway, thanks for the article. I found that's useful. @Daniel Bond.